# Join Query instead of 2 Select Queries

Tags: sql, join

The following query seems to be very slow

```
select * from employee where emp_city = 'chennai' and emp_key NOT in 
(select emp_key from emp_details)
```

This query is executing very slow when the data is very huge

Instead of 2 select queries,

1. how to create a query using join for the above
2. will join query will be much faster then 2 select queries.

Please kindly advise

Comment: What database? Also, please provide DDL (`create table` statements) for `employee` and `emp_details`.

Comment: emp_key is the indexed primary key column. Most of the columns are not indexed. However it is not part of the table.

Comment: Select * from employee e left join emp_details ed on e.emp_key = ed.emp_key and ed.emp_key is null  where e.where emp_city = 'chennai'

Comment: Will the query will be different for mysql, mssql and oracle. I want to write it for mysql, mssql and oracle

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is MySQL, this could be joined as follows:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN emp_details d
ON e.emp_key = d.emp_key
WHERE e.emp_city = "chennai"
AND d.emp_key IS NULL;
```

Comment: Will the query will be different for mysql, mssql and oracle. I want to write it for mysql, mssql and oracle

Comment: This exact query would be the same for both MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: how about MSSQL...is the query needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing this using `not exists` *and* implementing the correct indexes:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.emp_city = 'chennai' and
      not exists (select 1 from emp_details ed where ed.emp_key = e.emp_key);
```

Then the two indexes you want are:

- `emp_details(emp_key)`
- `employee(emp_city, emp_key)`

Of the two, the first is probably more important.

Comment: This query would be the same for MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon Linoff...Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Is not exists is faster than left join query. Paul suggested Left Join query. Please let me know your thoughts which one to go

Comment: @JavaArch . . . They should be pretty similar.  You would need to test on your data on the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I think `exists` is faster than `in`, you can try this

```
select * 
from employee e
where emp_city = 'chennai'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from emp_details d 
        where e.emp_key = d.emp_key
    )
```

Comment: This query would be the same for MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle ?